# Question about Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose $X(t) = e^{-t/2}W(e^{t})$ is an Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process ($W(t)$ is a Wiener process) and $\epsilon > 0$. I'm trying to find a constant $\delta>0$ so that
$$
\lim_T\mathbb{P}\Big( \sup_{0 \leq t\leq T}|X(t)|^2 + \epsilon < \sup_{0 \leq t\leq T(1+\delta)}|X(t)|^2\Big) \approx 1.
$$
By a version of the law of the iterated logarithm, I know that
$$
\lim_T (2\log(T))^{-1}\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T}|X(t)|^2 = 1 \quad a.s.,
$$
so that $$ \sup_{0 \leq t \leq T}|X(t)|^2 \approx 2\log(T), \quad \sup_{0 \leq t \leq T(1+\delta)}|X(t)|^2 \approx 2\log(T(1+\delta)) = 2\log(T) + 2\log(1+\delta) \quad a.s. $$ Thus, I'm tempted to just choose $\delta$ so that $ 2\log(1+\delta) > \epsilon $, but I'm worried this intuition is flawed. Any help making this more rigorous would be much appreciated.

Comment: I believe one issue with this is that you want this to hold for all $T$, not just $T$ sufficiently large for the law of iterated logarithm to come into play in this way.  However, the way the question is currently written is somewhat confusing because that probability can be made arbitrarily close to $1$ by sending $\delta \rightarrow \infty$, and usually $\delta$ represents a small number.  Are you sure the statement you are trying to show is written correctly?

Comment: Sorry I should clarify that it can hold for $T\rightarrow\infty$. Ideally I'd like to obtain a relationship between $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ so that if $\epsilon$ is small then so is $\delta$.